# How to detect Tab show/hide in Xamarin Forms and XAML

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am using following code to implement tabbed page in my xamarin forms app:

```
public class MainApp : TabbedPage
{
    public MainApp ()
    {
        this.Children.Add (new PanicPage{Title="Panic", Icon="icon_panic" });
        this.Children.Add (new StatusPage{Title="Status", Icon="icon_status" });
        this.Children.Add (new ConfigPage{Title="Config", Icon="icon_config"  });           
    }

}
```

I need to detect when particular tab is being shown or is it hidden. How can I do this in Xamarin forms?

Answer (score 1):

There is a virtual method
**OnCurrentPageChanged**
Override this, then check **CurrentPage** property

Answer (score 0):

There is TabbedPage.CurrentPage property. You can either bind your view-model property to it or write code like this:

```
this.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => {
    if (e.PropertyName == "CurrentPage")
    {
        //TODO
    }
};
```

Comment: For example in existing code before adding child pages.